# How to Write a Script For User Input Values in Multiple Files in Their Respective Directories

Tags: automation, user-input

Automation is the goal here

Cannot figure out how write a script to do what I need

This is for Emulation config files for Retro Arch. I have 2 light guns that use mouse index Id's for different emulator cores. Sometimes when rebooting the indexes will get re-assigned and I have to manually change the indexes manually. There is a tool called 'Controller Remap' that will detect these indexes and edit these config files...  but it always is wrong.

I am hoping for a script where it will ask me to input a number value for the 2 indexes I need to change and execute all of them.

Config files that need to be edited (these files are in their own directories)

`PSX.cfg`
`SATURN.cfg`
`WII.cfg`
`FinalBurnNeo.cfg`
`ATOMISWAVE.CFG`
`DREAMCAST.CFG`
`NAOMI.CFG`
`GENESIS.CFG`
`SMS.CFG`
`SNES.CFG`

Lines that need user input changes "?"

`input_player1_mouse_index = "1"`
`input_player2_mouse_index = "2"`

So when running a script a popup window should display
"Please input mouse index value for Player 1 and Player 2" Or something to that effect.

I am not sure how this can be done, anyone know if it is possible and how would it be done?